# ¿Cómo mostrar el valor asociado a una frecuencia en una tabla?

Tags: rstudio

Necesito calcular la moda de una manera alternativa a la común y se me ocurre que algo cuente el valor máximo en las frecuencias (en este caso 4) y me muestre el valor asociado a esta frecuencia,(en este caso 156), pero no sé cual función me sirve para mostrar ese valor asociado al número máximo en las frecuencias.

| fila | value | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 145 | 1 |
| 2 | 156 | 4 |
| 3 | 165 | 1 |
| 4 | 175 | 2 |
| 5 | 187 | 2 |
| 6 | 192 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes las frecuencias en un data.frame como el que muestras:

```
df <- read.table(text="
fila/ value / count
1 / 145 / 1
2 / 156 / 4
3 / 165 / 1
4 / 175 / 2
5 / 187 / 2
6/ 192 / 1", sep="/", header=TRUE)
```

Puedes usar `which.max()` para obtener el número de fila del valor máximo y usar este dato luego para obtener el valor en sí:

```
df$value[which.max(df$count)]
```